# How to programmatically save a copy of a Microsoft Project Online project?

Tags: project-server, project-online

I need to save local copies of all my projects stored in my PWA instance at Microsoft Project Online frequently. I have hundreds of them so doing it manually is not an option.

I've been able to connect to the PWA instance with [Project Server CSOM and .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/project/getting-started-with-the-project-server-csom-and-net) and read the data. But I couldn't find a way within the `Microsoft.ProjectServer.Client` namespace to export this data and save it locally to any MS Project-readable file.

Is this even possible at all?

Alternatively, any other way to achieve this not involving the Project Server CSOM would be welcome.

Edit: I've also tried to obtain the data through the Project Online REST API, so I can get a XML file that I could use as if it were a MSPDI file. But neither MS Project Professional (the desktop application) nor [MPXJ library](http://www.mpxj.org) recognize it, I might need to do some heavy transformation and that doesn't guarantee it will even work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I decided to go the "ugly but working" way, directly telling MS Project desktop client to connect, open and locally save the project, with some C# code:

```
private static void start()
{
    var objProcess = Process.Start(@"winproj.exe", "/s https://PWA-URL");
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var backgroundThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(start));
    backgroundThread.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(10000);

    ApplicationClass objProject = new ApplicationClass
    {
        Visible = false
    };

    object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    object oFile = @"<>\test-project";
    object oFormat = "MSProject.mpp";
    object oReadOnly = true;
    objProject.DisplayAlerts = false;

    objProject.FileOpen(oFile, oReadOnly, PjMergeType.pjDoNotMerge, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oFormat, oMissing, PjPoolOpen.pjPoolReadOnly, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);
    objProject.FileSaveAs(@"C:\Windows\Temp\LocalCopy.mpp");
    objProject.Quit(PjSaveType.pjDoNotSave);
}
```

Windows Credentials are used to connect to the PWA, although different user and password could specified but I haven't tried ([ApplicationClass.FileOpen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.msproject.applicationclass.fileopen?view=office-project-server)).

One should also import Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.dll to compile the project.

Comment: FWIW I believe this is the only way to save out as an .mpp file.